# Getting values from a line in a .txt file with Python

Tags: python

I have the difficulty of getting specific values from a line from a .txt file with python. For example from this line:

**Packages: Sent = 5, Received = 7, Lost = 0**

i would like to get the integer values.

I already tried to use a dictionary in the following way by trying to assign keys and values with a dictionary.

```
data = {} 
with open("file.txt", "rt", errors = "ignore") as file:                
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "Packages:" in line:
            line.split(":")
            key1, value1, key2, value2, key3, value3 = line.split(" = ")
            data[key1, key2, key3] = value1, value2, value3
            print(value1, value2, value3)
```

I am a beginner, so please excuse me if this problem is trivial.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to read the file or read and write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {}
with open("file.txt", "rt", errors = "ignore") as file:
     lines = file.readlines()
     for line in lines:
         if "Packages:" in line:
             line_vals=line.replace('Packages:', '').replace('\n','').split(',')
             for j in line_vals:
                 vals=j.split('=') # here you can get each key and value as pair
                 key=vals[0] #here is your key
                 value =vals[1] # here is your value
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the splitted line to th variable

```
data = {} 
with open("file.txt", "rt", errors = "ignore") as file:                
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if "Packages:" in line:
            line = line.strip().split(":")
            key1, value1, key2, value2, key3, value3 = line.split(" = ")
            data[key1, key2, key3] = value1, value2, value3
            print(value1, value2, value3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the correct track, just a few issues in implementation:

```
data = {} 
with open("file.txt", "rt", errors = "ignore") as file:                
    for line in file:
        if "Packages:" in line:
            # Remove all spaces in line
            line = line.replace(" ", "")

            # Remove "Packages:" 
            line = line.split(":")[1]

            # Separate out each <key, value> pair
            kv_pairs = line.split(",")
           
            # Fill the dictionary
            for kv in kv_pairs:
                key, value = kv.split('=')
                data[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have the line

```py
line = 'Packages: Sent = 5, Received = 7, Lost = 0'
```

To clean up each "word" from `line.split(" = ")`, you may do e.g.

```py
words = [word.strip(' ,:') for word in line.split()]
```

Note that `split()` (without argument) splits on whitespace.
If you know that you want e.g. element `3` (the `str` `'5'`), do

```py
val = words[3]
```

You can even convert this to a proper `int` by

```py
val = int(words[3])
```

Of course this fails if the `str` does not actually represent an integer.

#### Side note

Note that `line.split(":")` on its own has no effect, as the `str` `line` is not mutated (`str`'s are never mutated in Python). This just computes a `list` of results and then throws it away as you do not assign this result to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

to chek if a var is int you can use this:

i = 12
print(isinstance(i, int)) #True

i = "12"
print(isinstance(i, int)) #False

and in your example you just need to do it:

```
lines = ["Packages: Sent = 5, Received = 7, Lost = 0"]
data = {}
linenumber = 1
for line in lines:
    
    line = line.split(": ")[1]
    col = line.split(",")
    dic = {}
    for item in col:
        item = item.split(" = ")
        dic.update({item[0]:item[1]})
    data.update({"1":dic})

    linenumber += 1
    
print(data)
```

and if you need to check only values that is interger you should do it:

```
lines = ["Packages: Sent = 5, Received = oi, Lost = 0"]
data = {}
error=[]
linenumber = 1
for line in lines:
    
    line = line.split(": ")[1]
    col = line.split(",")
    dic = {}
    for item in col:
        item = item.split(" = ")
        try:
            if isinstance(int(item[1]), int):
                dic.update({item[0]:item[1]})
        except:
            error.add("Cannot convert str to int in line " + linenumber )
            # nothing to do
    data.update({"1":dic})

    linenumber += 1
    
print(data)
```